# Visitor Counts in PHP stopped working suddenly

Tags: php, counter, visitor-statistic

I have visitor count script on my [website](http://jainvidhya.co.in/#visits).

It was working well until noon (ITC), but now it is not working, also all the files of counts are now not having any text, even a single character.

My Codes:

```
<?php
if (file_exists('date.txt')) {     
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Calcutta');
$cdatel = date('Y-m-d', time());

$dthandle = fopen("date.txt", "r"); //reads date
$date =  fread($dthandle,filesize("date.txt"));
fclose ($dthandle);
$tthandle = fopen("total.txt", "r"); //reads total count
$ttcounter =  fread($tthandle,filesize("total.txt"));
fclose ($tthandle);
$ttcounter++; //+1 for new count in total
$ttl = $ttcounter;
$tthandle = fopen("total.txt", "w" ); //write for total count
fwrite($tthandle,$ttcounter);
fclose ($tthandle);
if($cdatel == $date){ //checks whether date in file is same as current date
$handle = fopen("today.txt", "r"); //reads todays count
$counter =  fread($handle,filesize("today.txt"));
fclose ($handle);
$yhandle = fopen("yesterday.txt", "r"); //reads todays count
$yv =  fread($yhandle,filesize("yesterday.txt"));
fclose ($yhandle);
$counter++; //+1 for new count in todays
$tdy = $counter;
$handle = fopen("today.txt", "w" ); //write for todays count
fwrite($handle,$counter);
fclose ($handle); 
}
else{
$ttyhandle = fopen("date.txt", "w" );
fwrite($ttyhandle,$cdatel);
fclose ($ttyhandle);
$ttyhandle = fopen("today.txt", "r");
$tdycounter =  fread($ttyhandle,filesize("today.txt"));
fclose ($ttyhandle);
$zero = "0";
$tzhandle = fopen("today.txt", "w" );
fwrite($tzhandle,$zero);
fclose ($tzhandle); 
$ttyhandle = fopen("yesterday.txt", "w" );
fwrite($ttyhandle,$tdycounter);
fclose ($ttyhandle);
?>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; ./sitemap-generator.php">
<?php
}
} 
?>
```

Comment: Please properly format your code. It's hard to read.

Comment: May I suggest moving these values to a database.

Comment: @NigelRen Yes, nice idea... but may I get the reason of that happening?

Comment: Could be file permissions, or several other possibilities, but the method your using is potentially fragile (race conditions etc.) and so finding a working solution may be easier than trying to bug fix it.

Comment: u can check space on the server , it might be 100%